# In aws how to access service in a different region from a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

Consider the following situation in AWS:

1. A VPC  in region A with many servers.
2. A mysql service in a server with public IP in region B. This service's port(3306) is open to (0.0.0.0).

from any server in VPC that has public IP I can access the mysql server in region B but any server that `doesn't` have public IP is unable to access the server.

what is the reason for this? is it possible the servers without public IP access has different way of communicating in different way?

just as a NOTE:

the services without public IP seem to show the NAT's IP:

`curl http://icanhazip.com` result is: `NAT's public IP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The magic of stackoverflow that after hours of headache as soon as I post the question, I figure out the answer myself :/.

basically I needed to add an outbound rule to the VPC's security group.

```
port: 3306

Protocol : TCP 

Destination: the IP I'M TRYING TO CONNECT TO.
```

Comment: "VPC group" means "security group," presumably.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yeah security group that is used for our VPC.